# VBA compile error with set property for Date object

Tags: vba, compiler-errors

I'm fairly new to VBA code, and I'm running into a compile error when I try to run this code in a class I created.

```
Private pWorkDate As Date

Public Property Set WorkDate(value As Date)
Set pWorkDate = value
End Property

Public Property Get WorkDate() As Date
Set WorkDate = pWorkDate
End Property
```

This is the error message that I'm getting:

> Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray, or an invalid Set final parameter

Please forgive my ignorance, but I have been searching around and can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It dislikes your attempt to use `set` which is for object references, which a variable of type `Date` can never be (its a primitive type (like `integer`) not an object type (like your class)).

Change to `Let` & don't use `Set`:

```
Public Property Let WorkDate(value As Date)
   pWorkDate = value
End Property

Public Property Get WorkDate() As Date
   WorkDate = pWorkDate
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really bugging me. A lot of the places I was looking at kept referring to Dates as objects, which is why I assumed I would need a set. Thanks for the help!